# How can I make a Maven module only go until the test phase when the parent gets deployed?

Tags: java, maven, testing, build, multi-module

I'm working on a multi-module project. One of our module is a `tests` project, which tests the other modules.

First question: is it a good pratice?

The Maven build lifecycle phases are:

1. `validate`
2. `compile`
3. `test`
4. `package`
5. `integration-test`
6. `verify`
7. `install`
8. `deploy`

When installing or deploying the parent module, how can I make the `tests` module only go until the `test` phase, i.e. to skip package and following phases? Since the only purpose of this module is to test the other ones.

Comment: what is a goal(s) that you are running? a `deploy` goal?

Comment: @YuriG. Yes: when I'm running `deploy` on my parent, I want my `tests` project to be validated, compiled and tested, but not packaged, nor installed, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that it is a `jar` project. Look at the [Plugin Bindings for Default Lifecycle Reference](http://maven.apache.org/ref/3.3.3//maven-core/default-bindings.html#Plugin_bindings_for_jar_packaging).

Bind the default executions  of the `maven-jar-plugin`, `maven-install-plugin` and `maven-deploy-plugin` plugins to the `none` phase in the `pom.xml`

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-install-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-install</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.8.2</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-deploy</id>
            <phase>none</phase>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: One can also use `<configuration><skip>true</skip></configuration>` in each plugin.

Comment: @sp00m - yes, didn't think about that.